# MVC 5 Conversion Rate in Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application with some forms for data entry.

There are 4 fields where the user must introduce values in USD and I want to display ( in other empty fields ) the automatic conversion to the local currency.

For instance, the user introduces a value in USD and automatically the value in Yuans in displayed in the field right next to it.

With that purpose I've created a specific menu in Admin area where the users, with such kind of privileges, are able to define the conversion rate by year and by country ( ex. : Year : 2017 - Country : China - Conversion rate : 6.84 ).

In resume, what I want is to associate that conversion rate to the fields in the form to be automatically shown when the form in being filled.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NP_REVENUE, "CONTRACT REVENUE (USD)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4", style = "display:inline;" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NP_REVENUE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NP_REVENUE, "CONTRACT REVENUE (LOCAL)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4", style = "display:inline;" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NP_REVENUE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Use JQuery to capture the change event in the rate textbox and then set the value in the conversion text box.

Comment: Too broad, you need to learn Javascript

Comment: @Liam I appreciate your advice...but that's not going to solve my issue right now...that's why I came here...to seek for help...that's what you do when you are learning and you are humble enough to ask for it...

Comment: @tps - Liams correct. I can't write it for you...But to point you in the right direction look at Jquery selectors... specifically. $ ("#MyTextBox").change(). Have a go... if you get stuck.. come back.. post some more code and we'll take it from there! :)

Comment: @Wheels73 Thanks for your help